# How do you create a new fabric crashlytics Instant app?

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

Fabric app was creating with just fine with my other apps. Wait until I clicked on Instant app when I started my new project. Now I have two packages picked up by Fabric for the same project.

I installed crashlytics on one of the packages but still the app is not created in Fabric from Android studio.

Please help resolve, its been two days now i've build and run the app several times still no fabric App.

[image]

[image]

Comment: fabric is now integrated with google firebase crashlytics. So you might use that.

Answer (score 3):

First, Add the plugin to your android studio using below steps:
**File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Select `Fabric for Android Studio` -> Install it**

Finally, after install plugin, you can see Fabric icon in top toolbar also in right panel with fabric word select and log in,

From the fabric, menu select your project operation which will see in the panel next option(Code setup for fabric).

Comment: I just suggest make one crash in your app and run it in device after crash it will be visible in fabric.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat 3 times for those important things:

Fabric support for Google Instant Apps is not currently enabled. Contact support@fabric.io if you're interested in trying it!

Fabric support for Google Instant Apps is not currently enabled. Contact support@fabric.io if you're interested in trying it!

Fabric support for Google Instant Apps is not currently enabled. Contact support@fabric.io if you're interested in trying it!

but if you dont belive that , you can follow this 5 steps to validate it.

1. [image]  choose the package without **.feature**
2. [image] add dependencies to your  **project**/build.gradle file
3. add **apply plugin: 'io.fabric'** to your **base**/build.gradle file
4. add dependencies `compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
       transitive = true;
   }` to your **base**/build.gradle file
5. add `<meta-data
         android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
         android:value="your apikey" />`
   to your **base**/AndroidManifest.xml

click your Sync now

Comment: The issue is installing the crashnalitcs or Answers or FastLane in a instant app project. If you understand what I mean.

Comment: I tried this https://blog.epictimes.net/how-to-add-crashlytics-to-android-instant-apps-%EF%B8%8F-8b977e57546e from Epic Times. Still no success

Comment: when u finish it  and after run your app, u can find this app is in https://fabric.io/settings/apps